# typeof(T) for inner list

Tags: c#, generics, typeof

I am trying to deserialise a xml output from a REST API. After deserialising, I need to check whether the response has valid data.

```
public class Response
{
 public UserWrapper Users { get; set; }
 public MovieWrapper Movies { get; set; }
}

public class UserWrapper
{
    [XmlElement("User")]
    public User[] UserList { get; set; }
}

public class MovieWrapper
{
    [XmlElement("Movie")]
    public Movie[] MovieList { get; set; }
}

public static bool isValidUserResponse(this Response response)
{
 return response.Users != null && response.Users.UserList != null
}

 public static bool isValidMovieResponse(this Response response)
{
 return response.Movies!= null && response.Movies.MovieList != null
}
```

**XML Response Structure**

```
<Response>
 <Users>
  <User>...</User>
  <User>...</User>
  <User>...</User>
 </Users>
</Response>

<Response>
 <Movies>
  <Movie>...</Movie>
  <Movie>...</Movie>
  <Movie>...</Movie>
 </Movies>
</Response>
```

How do I make my isValidUserResponse() and isValidMovieResponse() as single generic method?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking - we have no idea where `MovieList` would come into anything, or what `Response` is, etc. Please provide more context - and example of how you'd do this *without* generics would be a good start... (I'd also recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions, and change your method body to `return response.Users != null && response.Users.UserList != null;`.)

Comment: I would start name your list `List` instead of `UserList`, `MovieList` etc. That would make matching using an interface possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated my question. Hope this helps. Also thanks for insisting me on .NET conventions.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just use generics for this - at least, not easily. You *could* write something like:

```
public static void IsValidResponse<T>(this Response response,
    Func<Response, T> firstPropertyFetcher,
    Func<T, object> secondPropertyFetcher) where T : class
{
    T property = firstPropertyFetcher(response);
    return property != null && secondPropertyFetcher(property) != null;
}
```

and call it with:

```
response.IsValidResponse(r => r.Users, u => u.UserList);
response.IsValidResponse(r => r.Movies, u => u.MovieList);
```

... but I'm not sure that's any cleaner.

Or you *could* use reflection to examine all of the properties within `Response` and find ones with the "target" type, and validate those... but it's a bit ugly.

Do you need to validate each part of the response separately? If not, you could consider giving each class its own `IsValid` method.

Alternatively, I believe there are some general open source validation projects which may help you - but I don't have any experience with them.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Response
{
    public UserWrapper Users { get; set; }
    public MovieWrapper Movies { get; set; }

    public Response()
    {
        Users = new UserWrapper();
        Movies = new MovieWrapper();
    }

    public bool IsValid<T>() where T : IList
    {
        var property = this.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public).First(p => p.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(T)));
        var collection = property.GetValue(this) as IList;
        return collection.Count > 0;
    }
}

public class User
{
    // ...
}

public class Movie
{
    // ...
}

public class UserWrapper : List<User>
{
    // ...
}

public class MovieWrapper : List<Movie>
{
    // ...
}
```

And then we get:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var res = new Response();
            res.Users.Add(new User());
            Console.WriteLine(res.IsValid<UserWrapper>().ToString()); // "true"
            Console.WriteLine(res.IsValid<MovieWrapper>().ToString()); // "false"
        }
```

So here's what's happening: `this.GetType()` Gives us `Response` Type object, which stores all the metadata about it; We get all the public properties that belong to the instance and we look for the first one with the return type (`PropertyType`) which is identical to the one we're looking for: `T` type.
We use the `property` to get the relevant collection from the instance (`property.GetValue(this)`) and then we just count it.

Notice that if you have two properties of the same type - this pattern won't work.